# How to merge three Excel files rows into one?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am new to Excel.  I want to merge three Excel files into one. They all have the same column headers.

I have three files of students. Each file contain only 100 students. Each file has the same headings: **Student_name**, **Rollno.**, and **Class**.

How can I merge all 300 students into one file?

Comment: I think what you are describing is just a copy/paste problem. You open all three files, copy from one and paste at the end of the other, repeat and then you have all your data in only one file

Comment: If there is only 3 files with only one sheet each, I think copy-pasting is faster than waiting for an answer here

Comment: @fernando.reyes That was a lot easier then I thought . Thanks:)

Comment: @fernando.reyes, you should post your response as the answer - get the credit and get this one off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are describing is just a copy/paste problem.

When you have data spread into several files, with the same headers, the easier way to merge them is to open all three files, copy from one and paste at the end of the other, repeat and then you have all your data in only one file.